# Learn Payment Gateway, SSL and PCI DSS compliance checking - PHP

Tags: php, ssl, pci-dss

I am wanting to learn how to develop a payment gateway in PHP and the best practices(such as SSL and PCI DSS etc). Can anybody recommend any books/blogs that would help me with this, everything I have found is payment gateway specific and hasn't helped me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an article a few years back that covers the basics of ecommerce. It's called [Ecommerce 101](http://www.merchant-account-services.org/article/ecommerce-101). Hopefully you find it helpful.

Comment: Problem loading the page. is this something down at your end or miss spelling?

Comment: Just loaded for me. It's on a shared server so it's always possible it wasn't before.

Comment: Still getting the same 'Server not found' error, I have even tried IE.